# c# WPF Mainwindow button is not recognized in UserControl code?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

In the xaml of the Mainwindow a button has been created with the name "btnDel" which is by default "Visibility = false".
In my UserControlRDV.xaml.cs code I want to make that button visible with "MainWindow.btnDel.Visibility = true".
Here I get an error CS0120 "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'MainWindow.btnDel' ?

Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: "*In my UserControlRDV.xaml.cs code I want to make that button visible*" - you hopefully won't really do that. It would make your control dependent on the MainWindow in which is it used, which is a clear design error. Bind the Button's Visibility to a property of the control instead.

Comment: Hey there, you seem to be new to the topic. it doesnt make any sense to have the usercontrol access the main window directly in the fashion you describe. The usercontrol and the Mainwindow do not share the same scope thus they cant access each other as if they were in the same class

Comment: The typical MVVM approach here would be to bind the Command property of the Button to an ICommand property of a view model that would be shared by the MainWindow and the UserControl.

Comment: Ok have you example of this ? thanks

Comment: `MainWindow.btnDel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`  the visibility property isn't a bool.

Comment: @FelixCastor `MainWindow.btnDel` is still invalid.

Comment: Thanks, stupid of my thanks Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to the parent window of the `UserControl` using the `Window.GetWindow` method:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
if (mainWindow != null)
    mainWindow.btnDel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: thanks mm8 correct solved now